# Change radio input name - disappear radio checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a question about change input number at the name attribute via box order. When I change input names in the first box, the second box with radio input lose his checked value.

```
$('.container').find('.box').each(function (idx) {
            $(this).find('input').each(function () {
                let field = $(this);
                let fieldName = field.attr('name');
                let mIndex = 0;

                if (fieldName.length !== 0) {
                    field.attr('name', fieldName.replace(
                      /\[\d+]/g, 
                      function (match, pos, original) {
                          return mIndex++ === 0 ? '[' + idx + ']' : match;
                      }));
                    field.attr('id', field.attr('name').replace(/[\[\]]/g, '#').replace(/\#+/g, '-').replace(/[-]+$/g, ''));
                    field.closest('.field').children('label').attr('for', field.attr('id'))
                }
            });
```

Here is my code with example: https://jsfiddle.net/pbLkabhe/

My question is how to fix the Javascript code to stay radio input checked value after change input name.

Comment: I don't see any faults in your form.

Comment: The second box don't show input radio checked option (http://prntscr.com/fl5794)

Answer (score 0):

All your radios are being treated as the same radio group, because they have the same name (The square backets do not make them a separate group). This means only 1 of them will ever be checked. I have changed the name of the second set of radio buttons, so now both the radio sets have the correct radio checked.

```
<label>
  <input id="box-0-radio" name="hello[0][radio]" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked">        
  Option 3
 </label>
 <label>
   <input id="box-0-radio" name="hello[0][radio]" type="radio" value="1">
    Option 4
 </label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pbLkabhe/1/

Comment: But i dont want to change name i want save the name with box[{number}][{Name}]. I might have some box with fields, for example 6-9 box with input radio where name is box[0], box[1], box[2], ....etc.

Comment: If a radio button has the same name, regardless of the square brackets, only one of them can be checked at a time. That is just how radio button work. There is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Maybe I can do it with tmp variable old value, set new and set tmp to the new name?